# R2DBC batch, performance issue

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, r2dbc

My business case requires 10-15k records to be inserted in one transaction as quickly as possible. In this case, a batch insert seems to be a natural choice, but:

1. Performance is very different depending on the database. My target database is Azure SQL. The same test, inserting 10k records on H2 takes 5-10s, on Azure SQL/SQL Server ~ 50s. I don’t know the internals of Azure SQL, but this database seems to be more performant.
2. Batch only provides one add method whose parameter is a SQL string. Is there any reason why there is no saveAll equivalent with a list of objects as a parameter?
3. Azure SQL/SQL Server provides Table-Valued Parameters functionality. I did the same test inserting 10k records - JDBC. Time is ~ 5s. Unfortunately, R2DBC, SQL Server driver does not currently support TVP. I can see, “Next steps: Add support for TVP and UDTs”. When is it planned to be added? I would prefer batch, to be database agnostic, but performance is crucial in my case.

Comment: What are you *actually* asking here. Your question is laid out like you are asking several questions here (a question should be limited to one question), though your first bullet point doesn't have a question, and the last bullet point is a question for the support team/developer of the driver.

Comment: All is related to performance. What is the best way to write 10k records using R2DBC?

Comment: "What is best" isn't an on topic question at all; such questions are almost certainly going to result in opinionated answers.